# Triggering an event on clicking the Dropdown in angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a Dropdown as a ng-select. I want to trigger an event on clicking the Dropdown box. Is it possible to achieve this functionality? I have tried with ng-click / click event, but I couldn't able to reproduce.

Here is the code sample:

```
<label>Template :</label>
<div >
<ng-select #referenceSelect [allowClear]="true" [items]="referenceList"  
      (click)="temp($event)" [(ngModel)]="referenceTaskSlNo">
</ng-select>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried the '(open)' event?

Comment: Can you put the code snippet for your temp function.

Comment: I just had an alert() fn inside the temp(). I tried to debug too, but on clicking the dropdown, there was no response.

Answer (score 0):

I think the (open) event will do tthe job : https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select#api

Comment: Do we need to provide in the div element or in the ng-select element?

Comment: In the ng-select element, just where your (click) event is placed :

Comment: `<label>Template :</label>
<div >
<ng-select #referenceSelect [allowClear]="true" [items]="referenceList"  
      (open)="temp($event)" [(ngModel)]="referenceTaskSlNo">
</ng-select>
</div>`

Comment: What do you mean with "not achievable" ?

Comment: I mean there is no response and the function couldn't be called when i tried to debug the code.

Comment: I tried and it works fine for me, the temp function() is called in my component.ts when opening the ng-select. Just that the $event is undefined, but it just mean that the open event is not giving you an event, it's just firing you function.